# What does # do in Java methods?

Tags: java, methods, syntax

I've seen some notation or style like `Region#layoutInArea()` for example. How does this act on a method? Is it related to the dot (**`.`**) accessor?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

That notation `Region#layoutInArea()` is not code - it's the way you refer to a method in javadoc.

Using it will create a hyperlink in the rendered documentation that links to the specified method's javadoc.

An example of its use:

```
/**
  * Does something.
  * @see Region#layoutInArea()
  */
public void doSomething() {
    //
}
```

It could used in other tags too, like `@link`.

Comment: @user2246674 it's important to distinguish code from documentation. This is doc, and yes it's official.

Comment: How and *where* can I use it to specify such javadoc?